# icefaces 3 - Cannot reach the backing bean from pages inside WEB-INF

Tags: jsf-2, navigation, icefaces, web-inf, icefaces-3

I upgraded icefaces version from 1.8 to 3 and I'm facing the following problem:
everytime I call a method in a backing bean form pages inside WEB-INF, I have the error "Network connection interrupted" and, in firefox I see when I hover the button, POST mypage.jsf , STATUS 404 Not Found.
Can anybody help me, please?
If I move the pages outside WEB-INF it works, but I wouldn't change all the structure of my project...
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to move pages outside WEB-INF. This directory has a specific meaning in web application deployment. It holds configuration and (e.g.) classes used by servlet. 
Web container should not serve the content of this directory, if in 1.8 this happen, probably it's a bug that has been fixed.